# jquery $().val() на чистом javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть простой селект с кнопкой

```
<select id="select_example" >
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>


<button class = "random_btn">
  btn
</button>
```

script

```
$(".random_btn").on("click",function(){
    $("#select_example").val('3')
})
```

с использование jQuery все работает отлично, но я не понимаю как переписать это на чистом js. Перепробовал разные способы, но так ничего и не вышло

Comment: `select_example.value = '3'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.random_btn');
const select = document.querySelector('#select_example');

btn.addEventListener('click', () =>
{
  select.value = '3';
});
```

```html
<select id="select_example">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>


<button class="random_btn">
  btn
</button>
```